# Retrieving enum from set of values

Tags: enums, mapping

I have an enum something like this:

```
public enum Operation {
   ACK(1, false, false), NACK(255, false, false);
   ...
}
```

Now I have the loose values say `255`, `false`, `false`,
from which I would like to retrieve a `NACK` enum.

I need a function `f` so that:

```
f(255, false, false) returns NACK
f(1, false, false) returns ACK
```

How do I do this?